# Validate text box for numeric and/or alphabet and/or both

Tags: vb.net

I want to validate user's input into the `TextBox` whether it is numeric and/or alphabet and/or alphanumeric? Therefore, the `TextBox` must not include special characters.

Comment: what type of application you are using? and your need is to eliminate special characters in the textbox, isnt it?

Comment: i am using microsoft visual studio 2008. When user click a button, the validation for the text box will take place.

Comment: Dear..., is it Winforms? wpf?or web?

Comment: Winforms. Isn't VB.Net for application only?? Please tell me I'm not wrong because this is what I've thought for many years! =(

Comment: VB.Net can be used within an ASP.Net Web application environment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the validation to happen upon clicking a button, all at once (rather than when typing), there's a few different ways.

One would be to use `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to match non alpha numeric characters.

```
Dim pattern As Regex = New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
If pattern.IsMatch(myString) Then MsgBox("Not alphanumeric")
```

Another would be to use LINQ to check for non letters and non digits:

```
If Not TextBox1.Text.All(Function(ch) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch)) Then
    MsgBox("Non alphanumeric")
End If
```

[IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN

[IsLetterOrDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KeyPress` event to accept only particular character.

```
Private Sub YourTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles YourTextBox.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```